# Fast 1D linear np.NaN interpolation over large 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, interpolation

I have a 3D array `(z, y, x)` with `shape=(92, 4800, 4800)` where each value along `axis 0` represents a different point in time. The acquisition of values in the time domain failed in a few instances causing some values to be `np.NaN`. In other instances no values have been acquired and all values along `z` are `np.NaN`.

What is the most efficient way to use linear interpolation to fill `np.NaN` along `axis 0` disregarding instances where all values are `np.NaN`?

Here is a working example of what I'm doing that employs `pandas` wrapper to `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`. This takes around 2 seconds per slice on the original dataset meaning the whole array is processed in 2.6 hours. The example dataset with reduced size takes around 9.5 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create example data, original is (92, 4800, 4800)
test_arr = np.random.randint(low=-10000, high=10000, size=(92, 480, 480))
test_arr[1:90:7, :, :] = -32768  # NaN fill value in original data
test_arr[:, 1:90:6, 1:90:8] = -32768

def interpolate_nan(arr, method="linear", limit=3):
    """return array interpolated along time-axis to fill missing values"""
    result = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=np.int16)

    for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
        # slice along y axis, interpolate with pandas wrapper to interp1d
        line_stack = pd.DataFrame(data=arr[:,i,:], dtype=np.float32)
        line_stack.replace(to_replace=-37268, value=np.NaN, inplace=True)
        line_stack.interpolate(method=method, axis=0, inplace=True, limit=limit)
        line_stack.replace(to_replace=np.NaN, value=-37268, inplace=True)
        result[:, i, :] = line_stack.values.astype(np.int16)
    return result
```

Performance on my machine with the example dataset:

```
%timeit interpolate_nan(test_arr)
1 loops, best of 3: 9.51 s per loop
```

Edit:

I should clarify that the code is producing my expected outcome. The question is - how can I optimize this process?

Comment: Running the example takes about 9.5sec on my machine but the shape of test_arr is `(92, 480, 480)`. If you increase it to the size of the real dataset `(92, 4800, 4800)` and propagate it with more *NaN* this method takes considerably longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently solved this problem for my particular use case with the help of **numba** and also did [a little writeup on it](http://krstn.eu/fast-linear-1D-interpolation-with-numba/).

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def interpolate_numba(arr, no_data=-32768):
    """return array interpolated along time-axis to fill missing values"""
    result = np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=np.int16)

    for x in range(arr.shape[2]):
        # slice along x axis
        for y in range(arr.shape[1]):
            # slice along y axis
            for z in range(arr.shape[0]):
                value = arr[z,y,x]
                if z == 0:  # don't interpolate first value
                    new_value = value
                elif z == len(arr[:,0,0])-1:  # don't interpolate last value
                    new_value = value

                elif value == no_data:  # interpolate

                    left = arr[z-1,y,x]
                    right = arr[z+1,y,x]
                    # look for valid neighbours
                    if left != no_data and right != no_data:  # left and right are valid
                        new_value = (left + right) / 2

                    elif left == no_data and z == 1:  # boundary condition left
                        new_value = value
                    elif right == no_data and z == len(arr[:,0,0])-2:  # boundary condition right
                        new_value = value

                    elif left == no_data and right != no_data:  # take second neighbour to the left
                        more_left = arr[z-2,y,x]
                        if more_left == no_data:
                            new_value = value
                        else:
                            new_value = (more_left + right) / 2

                    elif left != no_data and right == no_data:  # take second neighbour to the right
                        more_right = arr[z+2,y,x]
                        if more_right == no_data:
                            new_value = value
                        else:
                            new_value = (more_right + left) / 2

                    elif left == no_data and right == no_data:  # take second neighbour on both sides
                        more_left = arr[z-2,y,x]
                        more_right = arr[z+2,y,x]
                        if more_left != no_data and more_right != no_data:
                            new_value = (more_left + more_right) / 2
                        else:
                            new_value = value
                    else:
                        new_value = value
                else:
                    new_value = value
                result[z,y,x] = int(new_value)
    return result
```

This is about *20 times faster* than my initial code.

Comment: would be interesting to see a cython comparison.

Comment: If anybody is able/willing to write that function in Cython I'd also love to see the speed comparison head to head.

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer. I have some new thoughts on the logic of linear interpolation. I have posted a new answer below and appreciate your attention!

Answer (score 3):

The questioner gave an excellent answer by taking advantage of `numba`. I really appreciate it but I cannot totally agree with the contents within `interpolate_numba` function. I do not think the logic of linear interpolation over a specific point is to find the average value of its left and right neighbors. For illustration, let's say we have an array [1,nan,nan,4,nan,6], the `interpolate_numba` function above will probably return [1,2.5,2.5,4,5,6] (only theoretical deduction), whereas `pandas` wrapper will surely return [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Instead, I believe the logic of linear interpolation over a specific point is to find its left and right neighbors, use their values to determine a line (i.e. slope and intercept), and finally calculate the interpolation value. The following shows my code. To make things easy, I assume the input data is a 3-D array containing nan values. I stipulate the first and last elements are equivalent to their right and left nearest neighbors (i.e. `limit_direction='both'` in `pandas`). I do not specify the maximum number of consecutive interpolations (i.e. no `limit` in `pandas`).

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def f(arr_3d):
    result=np.zeros_like(arr_3d)
    for i in range(arr_3d.shape[1]):
        for j in range(arr_3d.shape[2]):
            arr=arr_3d[:,i,j]
            # If all elements are nan then cannot conduct linear interpolation.
            if np.sum(np.isnan(arr))==arr.shape[0]:
                result[:,i,j]=arr
            else:
                # If the first elemet is nan, then assign the value of its right nearest neighbor to it.
                if np.isnan(arr[0]):
                    arr[0]=arr[~np.isnan(arr)][0]
                # If the last element is nan, then assign the value of its left nearest neighbor to it.
                if np.isnan(arr[-1]):
                    arr[-1]=arr[~np.isnan(arr)][-1]
                # If the element is in the middle and its value is nan, do linear interpolation using neighbor values.
                for k in range(arr.shape[0]):
                    if np.isnan(arr[k]):
                        x=k
                        x1=x-1
                        x2=x+1
                        # Find left neighbor whose value is not nan.
                        while x1>=0:
                            if np.isnan(arr[x1]):
                                x1=x1-1
                            else:
                                y1=arr[x1]
                                break
                        # Find right neighbor whose value is not nan.
                        while x2<arr.shape[0]:
                            if np.isnan(arr[x2]):
                                x2=x2+1
                            else:
                                y2=arr[x2]
                                break
                        # Calculate the slope and intercept determined by the left and right neighbors.
                        slope=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
                        intercept=y1-slope*x1
                        # Linear interpolation and assignment.
                        y=slope*x+intercept
                        arr[x]=y
                result[:,i,j]=arr
    return result
```

Initializing a 3-D array containing some nans, I have checked my code which can give as same answer as those from `pandas` wrapper. It will be a little bit confusing to go through `pandas` wrapper code since pandas can only address 2-dimensional data.

Using my code

```
y1=np.ones((2,2))
y2=y1+1
y3=y2+np.nan
y4=y2+2
y5=y1+np.nan
y6=y4+2
y1[1,1]=np.nan
y2[0,0]=np.nan
y4[1,1]=np.nan
y6[1,1]=np.nan
y=np.stack((y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6),axis=0)
print(y)
print("="*10)
f(y)
```

Using pandas wrapper

```
import pandas as pd
y1=np.ones((2,2)).flatten()
y2=y1+1
y3=y2+np.nan
y4=y2+2
y5=y1+np.nan
y6=y4+2
y1[3]=np.nan
y2[0]=np.nan
y4[3]=np.nan
y6[3]=np.nan
y=pd.DataFrame(np.stack([y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6],axis=0))
y=y.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='both', axis=0)
y_numpy=y.to_numpy()
y_numpy.shape=((6,2,2))
print(np.stack([y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6],axis=0).reshape(6,2,2))
print("="*10)
print(y_numpy)
```

Output will be the same

```
[[[ 1.  1.]
  [ 1. nan]]

 [[nan  2.]
  [ 2.  2.]]

 [[nan nan]
  [nan nan]]

 [[ 4.  4.]
  [ 4. nan]]

 [[nan nan]
  [nan nan]]

 [[ 6.  6.]
  [ 6. nan]]]
==========
[[[1. 1.]
  [1. 2.]]

 [[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]

 [[3. 3.]
  [3. 2.]]

 [[4. 4.]
  [4. 2.]]

 [[5. 5.]
  [5. 2.]]

 [[6. 6.]
  [6. 2.]]]
```

Using `test_arr` data increasing its size to (92,4800,4800) as input, I found only approximately 40 s was needed to complete the interpolation!

```
test_arr = np.random.randint(low=-10000, high=10000, size=(92, 4800, 4800))
test_arr[1:90:7, :, :] = np.nan  # NaN fill value in original data
test_arr[2,:,:] = np.nan
test_arr[:, 1:479:6, 1:479:8] = np.nan
%time f(test_arr)
```

Output

```
CPU times: user 32.5 s, sys: 9.13 s, total: 41.6 s
Wall time: 41.6 s
```

Comment: Great answer! My initial problem only contained 1 missing observation in a given series of numbers. However, yours is a nice solution that allows for more applications.

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

This depends; you will have to take out a sheet of paper and calculate the error your overall statistics will get if you *don't* interpolate and just zero-fill these *NaN*.

Other than that, I think your interpolation is over the top. 
Just find each NaN, and linearly interpolate to the adjacent four values (which is, sum up the values at (y +- 1,x +- 1) )  -- this will seriously limit your error enough (calculate yourself!), and you don't have interpolate with whatever complex method is used in your case (you didn't define `method`).

You can try to just pre-compute one "averaged" 4800x4800 matrix per z value -- this shouldn't really take long -- by applying a cross-shaped kernel across the matrix (it's all very image-processing-like, here). In case of NaN's, some of the averaged values will be NaN (every averaged pixel where a NaN was in the neighborliness), but you don't care -- unless there are two adjacent NaNs, the NaN cells that you want to replace in the original matrix are all real-valued.

Then you just replace all the NaNs by the value in the averaged matrix.

Compare the speed of that with the speed of "manual" calculation of the neighborhood average for every NaN you find.

Comment: The interpolation is really just a precursor for a classification according to the signal in the time domain so 0-filling is not an option. Linear interpolation is what I am doing at the moment with `method="linear"`. Replacing every *NaN* with the mean of it's z-axis is my fallback option if linear interpolation fails.

Comment: Um, the mean of the two surrounding z-values is *exactly* linear interpolation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the mean over all 92 values along the z-axis. OItherwise I'm stuck at the initial problem: What's the fastest way to interpolate over missing values along the z-axis.

Comment: I don't really understand -- the linear interpolation I outlined in my previous comment should be rather fast, and it's a valid interpolation

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly you areadvising 2D linear interpolation. I am going for 1D interpolation (for every NaN interpolate from z+-1). This is also what `pandas` wrapper to `scipy.signal.interp1d` does. My answer is more of a code optimization one than interpolation selection. Unless I understood your answer wrong and it is more efficient - in that case: Care to explain it with a code sample?

Comment: Ah, yes, I can see where I caused confusion. Sorry. My answer recommends 2D interpolation. My comment recommended that you just use the same approach to 1d interpolation: Take the previous and the next value in z direction and calculate the mean. It's the value that a linear interpolation would give you. Your Pandas approach somehow seems to take **all** 92 z-values into account (at least that's what I interpret from the runtime).

Comment: To sum that up: The basic idea is to precalculate a "mean-array" with the mean value of neighbours along the z-axis. Then find all the indices of of *NaN* and replace them with the according value from the pre-calculated "mean-array"? I do think this could be very fast but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem of consecutive *NaN* unless I employ a lot of (slow) loops.

Comment: ah, there's consecutive NaNs ? Then you should use correlation in something different than the z-axis.
To specify a question I should have asked before writing my answer: Are cells in the constant-z 4800x4800 matrices correlated? My approach was to use that correlation; if there's no such correlation, my answer was plainly useless.

Comment: There is no correlation in the x,y dimension (4800x4800), only along the z axis (92). Your answer still helped me get a new view on the issue, even though it didn't solve my particular problem. So, thank you for trying and putting in the time.

Comment: @Kersten, you're welcome :) so basically, you have 4800² uncorrelated vectors of length 92.