# Conditional Interpolation In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has random NA values, and I'd like to interpolate the original dataframe only over rows when the value of another column is 1.

I've tried `df[df['Flag' == 1]].interpolate(method='linear')`, but I have a large dataframe and it seems to be pretty slow. I've thought about using `np.where(df['Flag] == 1, df.interpolate(method='linear'))`, but I'm not sure if that's any more appropriate or even makes since, really.

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910944/fast-1d-linear-np-nan-interpolation-over-large-3d-array

Comment: I'd rather interpolate everything and reinsert null values where `flag != 0`.